# How to split a an array into several smaller arrays based on a given criterium between neighbours

Tags: python, arrays, split, wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica has two very useful functions to group an array into a list of smaller arrays based on given criteria: Split[] and SplitBy[] which I need to emulate in Python3 code:

Split[list,test] treats pairs of adjacent elements as identical whenever applying the function *"test"* to them yields True,

SplitBy[list,f] splits list into sublists consisting of runs of successive elements that give the same value when *f* is applied.

Thus if

```
a=[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]
```

Split[a,(#2-#1 < 4)&] gives:

```
[[2,3,5,7],[11,13],[17,19],[23],[29]]
```

and SplitBy[a,(Mod[#,2]==0)&] gives:

```
[[2],[3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]]
```

In practice the array to be split might be a 2-dimensional table and the test functions might work on the elements in individual columns.

How can this behaviour coded efficiently in Python3?

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a quick answer for the first part of your question, and lenik already provide a nice `zip`-based solution, but `SplitBy` can easily be reproduced using the `groupby` function of the `itertools` module ([doc here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)).

Beware, `groupby` will insert a separator (~ create a new group) each time the key change. So if you want something like `SplitBy`, you have to sort it according to the key function first.

In the end, it will give you something like this:

```
>>> def split_by(l, func):
        groups = []
        sorted_l = sorted(l, key=func)
        for _, g in it.groupby(sorted_l, key=func):
            groups.append(list(g)) 
        return groups

>>> split_by([2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29], lambda x: x%2)                                                                                                                                                                     
[[2], [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]]
```

One-liner version using list comprehension:

`splited_by = [list(g) for _, g in it.groupby(sorted(l, key=func), key=func)]`

Quick timeit benchmark on my old and broken laptop:

- itertools version

`>>> %timeit split_by([2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29], lambda x: x%2)
8.42 µs ± 92.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

- zip version

`>>> %timeit split_by([2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29], lambda x: x%2)
10.8 µs ± 53.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

- try/catch version

`>>> %timeit split_by([2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29], lambda x: x%2)
12.6 µs ± 162 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

Comment: If the downvoter could at least give a feedback or explain why I'm wrong, I'll be glad to improve this answer.

Comment: I dowvoted your answer but let me clarify why, I don't think the answer was wrong but it was a bit short, if you wrapped your way into a couple of functions split/split_by and posted a brief snippet applied to the proposed op's example that would be more than enough to upvote your answer in the first place. FYI, i don't like downvoting but in this case I considered the post quite interesting and these fast answers didn't make justice to the original question :)

Comment: @BPL Thanks for your feedback, I've just updated my answer ;)

Comment: Ok, +1 then ;) . And sorry, when I downvoted I should have provided feedback straightaway wihout you asking for. In fact, that's something I always encourage to people who downvote my answers in order to improve them. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting stats, thanks to post them. In fact, that's something I wanted to check yesterday when I posted my answer, if the overhead of having the inner try/catch was too big and yeah, it seems it was actually.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some possible solutions:

a) Using python builtin zip

```
def split(lst, test):
    res = []
    sublst = []

    for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
        sublst.append(x)
        if not test(x, y):
            res.append(sublst)
            sublst = []

    if len(lst) > 1:
        sublst.append(lst[-1])
        if not test(lst[-2], lst[-1]):
            res.append(sublst)
            sublst = []

    if sublst:
        res.append(sublst)

    return res


def split_by(lst, test):
    return split(lst, lambda x, y: test(x) == test(y))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
    print(split(a, lambda x, y: y - x < 4))
    print(split_by(a, lambda x: (x % 2) == 0))
```

b) for-loop with inner try/except:

```
def split(lst, test):
    res = []
    sublst = []

    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        try:
            y = lst[i + 1]
            sublst.append(x)
        except IndexError:
            x, y = lst[i - 1], lst[i]
            sublst.append(y)

        if not test(x, y):
            res.append(sublst)
            sublst = []

    if sublst:
        res.append(sublst)

    return res


def split_by(lst, test):
    return split(lst, lambda x, y: test(x) == test(y))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
    print(split(a, lambda x, y: y - x < 4))
    print(split_by(a, lambda x: (x % 2) == 0))
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 5, 7], [11, 13], [17, 19], [23], [29]]
[[2], [3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]]
```

Comment: `29` is missing from the output. if you copy-paste my code, at least don't leave important parts out...

Comment: @lenik Edited my answer but please clarify me something, the fact I considered using builtin python zip from your deleted answer was enough reason to downvote+comment I've copy-pasted your code? My previous answer was structurally different than yours so to me it felt more like a simple childish downvote. I may be wrong though, peace :)